# Hybrid SQL Proc, adding dynamic where clus depending on what parameters are passed in?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I would like to build a stored proc, but the where clus is becoming tricky as it changes dependent on what has been passed in.

On the front end i have 3 check box's that can be selected. These represent company size.
I have 7 company size's in my database.
Where if small is checked my where class would need to be:

Example:

Small Checked.

```
WHERE Size = Unclasified AND Size = VerySmal AND Size = Small
```

Medium Checked.

```
WHERE Size = Medium AND Size = MediumLarge
```

Large Checked.

```
WHERE Size = Large AND Size = Huge
```

Now since these are check box's they call all be checked or just have one or two checked.

So i would like to build my where clus first and then add it later:

```
DECLARE @SizeCatWhereClus varchar(MAX)
SET @SizeCatWhereClus = 'cm.sizecat=' + 'H: UNCLASSIFIED' + 'AND cm.sizecat= ...'



WHERE @SizeCatWhereClus
```

Is this possible? And if not are there any suggestions i can follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately dynamic sql in SQL Server has an "All or Nothing" quality to it. If you want to be dynamically generating the WHERE clause, you have to generate the entire query in a variable and then `EXECUTE` that variable. This is generally a bad idea in Sql Server for both security and performance reasons.

Fortunately, for your specific problem, dynamic sql isn't actually necessary, since your `WHERE` clauses can be combined using logical operators to get the result you want.

```
DECLARE @SmallChecked BIT, @MediumChecked BIT, @LargeChecked BIT
-- set the values of the @...Checked variables to the values of your checkboxes
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] 
 WHERE (@SmallChecked = 1 AND Size IN ('Unclassified', 'VerySmall', 'Small'))
    OR (@MediumChecked = 1 AND Size IN ('Medium', 'MediumLarge'))
    OR (@LargeChecked = 1 AND Size IN ('Large', 'Huge'))
```